# Регулярное выражение для разбора строки в файле

Tags: java

есть файл с множеством строк, но из файла мне нужно лишь несколько строк. А именно вопросы и ответы на них

Помимо всего прочего в файле есть такой кусок кода

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Question">
<h1 itemprop="name">Какое геометрическое тело получается вращением круга вокруг своего диаметра?</h1>


<h2>Варианты ответа:</h2>
<div class="variants">
<div itemprop="acceptedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer" class="one-fourth correct"><span itemprop="text">шар</span></div>
<div itemprop="suggestedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer" class="one-fourth"><span itemprop="text">цилиндр</span></div>
<div itemprop="suggestedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer" class="one-fourth"><span itemprop="text">конус</span></div>
<div itemprop="suggestedAnswer" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Answer" class="one-fourth"><span itemprop="text">пирамида</span></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Как мне составить регулярное выражение для поиска в файле строк, которые содержат текст:

1. `<h1 itemprop="name">`
2. `<div itemprop="acceptedAnswer"`
3. `<div itemprop="suggestedAnswer"`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: а просто пример можно привести ?

Answer (score 1):

Вам правильно указали в комментариях: не стоит парсить html регулярными выражениями. Но если очень хочется:

```
.*itemprop="(name|acceptedAnswer|suggestedAnswer)".*
```

[Тут ссылка на пример](https://regex101.com/r/SikwK2/1)

Comment: Спасибо, я уже сделала через Matcher